# How to clip and mask sprites in Pixi.js like `clip-path` in CSS

Tags: html5-canvas, sprite, pixi.js

In CSS, we can mask/clip a square image inside a shape with `clip-path`, for example, `clip-path: ellipse(60px 40px at 75px 30px);` clips the image to an ellipse.

How can I clip a sprite into an ellipse in Pixi.js?

Answer (score 2):

Just draw a `PIXI.Graphics` with the specified dimension, then assign it to `sprite.mask`.

```
const sprite = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('image-file')
const mask = new PIXI.Graphics()
mask.beginFill(0x000000)
mask.drawEllipse(75, 30, 60, 40)
sprite.mask = mask
```